# Regex: match non-android mobile user agents

Tags: regex

I need to match an UA if it contains Mobile but not Android. I've tried with

```
Windows Phone|WPDesktop|BlackBerry|Opera Mini|Opera Mobi|Silk\/|Kindle|(?!.*Android).*Mobile.*|SymbianOS
```

But it doesn't always work.

Also, how can I exclude both 'Windows' and 'Android'? (considering that Windows fakes himself as Android and iPhone...)

Edit: some test strings (android, iphone, wp, others):

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.2; GT-I8190N Build/JZO54K)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.94 Mobile
>   Safari/537.36
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1 like Mac OS X)
>   AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D167
>   Safari/9537.53
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (Mobile; Windows Phone 8.1; Android 4.0; ARM; Trident/7.0;
>   Touch; rv:11.0; IEMobile/11.0; NOKIA; Lumia 930) like iPhone OS 7_0_3
>   Mac OS X AppleWebKit/537 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile Safari/537
>
> UCWEB/2.0 (Symbian; U; S60 V5; en-US; Nokia700) U2/1.0.0
>   UCBrowser/9.2.0.336 U2/1.0.0 Mobile

Solved thanks to @Avinash Raj:

All mobiles:

```
^(?:.*(Mobile|Android|iPhone|Windows Phone|WPDesktop|RIM|BlackBerry|Opera Mini|Opera Mobi|Silk\/|Kindle|Symbian).*)$
```

iOS only:

```
^(?:(?!.*?(?:Windows|Android)).*?iPhone.*)$
```

Android only:

```
^(?:(?!.*?(?:Windows)).*?Android.*)$
```

All but Android and iOS:

```
^(?:.*Windows Phone.*|.*WPDesktop.*|.*RIM.*|.*BlackBerry.*|.*Opera Mini.*|.*Opera Mobi.*|.*Silk\/.*|.*Kindle.*|(?!.*?(?:iPhone|Android)).*?Mobile.*|.*Symbian.*)$
```

Comment: Please provide test string (user agents) you don't want to match (and such you want match) and please improve the description of "doesn't always work"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below regexes.

```
^(?:Windows Phone|WPDesktop|BlackBerry|Opera Mini|Opera Mobi|Silk\/|Kindle|(?!.*?(?:Windows|Android)).*?Mobile.*|SymbianOS)$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bP8wA1/1)

OR

```
\b(?:Windows Phone|WPDesktop|BlackBerry|Opera Mini|Opera Mobi|Silk\/|Kindle|(?!.*?(?:Windows|Android)).*+Mobile.*+|SymbianOS)\b
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bP8wA1/2)